# Scala - ParHashMap does not have withDefault

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, hashmap

I am try to make a ParHashMap with a default value, but upon compilation with scalac, I get the following error.

> vmath.scala:41: error: type mismatch;  found   :
>   scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParMap[String,Double]  required:
>   scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double]
>       new FreqVec(values)
>                   ^ vmath.scala:8: error: value withDefault is not a member of scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParMap[String,Double]
>   var vals = values.par.withDefault(k => 0.0)

I hate to ask you to debug this for me, but I am confused because I have successfully done this with other maps (mutable and not parallel) without compilation error, and the scala documentation says that the function does exist [HERE](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParHashMap)

Here is a brief of my code

```
package vmath

import collection.immutable.Map
import collection.parallel.immutable.ParMap

class FreqVec(val values: Map[String, Double]) {
     var vals = values.par.withDefault(k => 0.0)
     ...
}

object FreqVec {
  def apply(values: Map[String, Double]) = {
    new FreqVec(values)
  }
  def apply(values: ParMap[String, Double]) = {
    new FreqVec(values)
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error #1 tells you are trying to pass a ParMap where a Map is expected. I do not see the withDefault missing error. Make sure you are not using an old version of scala compiler that does not support it.

Below is a version of code that compiled with scala 2.11.0.

```
class FreqVec(val values: Map[String, Double]) {
  var vals: ParMap[String, Double] = values.par.withDefault(k => 0.0)

}

class FreqParVec(val values: ParMap[String, Double]) {
  var vals: ParMap[String, Double] = values.withDefault(k=>0.0)
  var valsWithPar: ParMap[String, Double] = values.par.withDefault(k=>0.0)
}

object FreqVec {
  def apply(values: Map[String, Double]) = {
    new FreqVec(values)
  }
}

object FreqParVec {
  def apply(values: ParMap[String, Double]) = {
    new FreqParVec(values)
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that I am using Scala 2.9.2. The error with about the default value is on the third line of the errors I posted and runs onto the fourth line. I just installed Scala 2.11 and I got it to compile. Thank you.